# Apache Zeppelin with Java error: ';' expected but 'class' found

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I use Apache Spark's Java API to load data from some sources(like Cassandra and HDFS) for visualization in Apache Zeppelin. The code is using `SparkSql` and `SparkSession`, not `SparkContext` and tested successfully in IDE. I paste the full code (containing all codes that I run in IDE) into Zeppelin notebook and after running it through an error `error: ';' expected but 'class' found`. I think this error is a Scala error and I suspect does Zeppelin support Spark Java API?! If yes, how can I solve the problem?

Apache Zeppelin version: `0.7.3`
The following is the code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class LoadCSV {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, String> ops = new HashMap();
        ops.put("table", "grades");
        ops.put("keyspace", "zeppline");

        SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .master("local[*]")
                .appName("Java Spark SQL basic example")
                .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")
                .config("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042")
                .getOrCreate();

        Dataset<Row> df1 = spark.read()
                .format("csv")
                .option("header", true)
                .option("inferSchema", true)
                .csv("hdfs://localhost:54310/Data/Zeppline/grades.csv");


        Dataset<Row> df2 = spark.read()
                .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
                .options(ops)
                .load()
                .select("id","first_name", "last_name", "ssn", "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "final", "grade");

        df1.union(df2).createOrReplaceTempView("grades");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I suspect does Zeppelin support Spark JAVA API?

It does not. You can fin a full list of avialable interpreters on the Zeppelin website (https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/manual/interpreters.html) and there is no Java interpreter there.

Comment: Can I define a custom interpreter that support Spark Java API?

Comment: @SoheilPourbafrani You might be able to do that, but realistically you'll need JDK9 or later (with its REPL), which is not supported in Spark. And Java is not designed with interactivity in mind anyway, so why bother?

Comment: You know I want finally run Zeppelin Spark codes in YARN cluster, if so, I need to change the API to Scala or Python, yet ?